# How to switch from one layout to another layout in Android

Tags: android, layout, progress-bar

My thinking is a layout with a progressBar( determinate ) will be shown for 5 second when i open my app. After 5sec this layout will be replaced by another layout containing some buttons.
How to do that. Plz help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define all of the two layouts properties inside one layout under ViewFlipper

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lah"
    >
    <ViewFlipper 
        android:id="@+id/flipper"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        >

       <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:id="@+id/first_layout">
         .
         .

         .

       </LinearLayout> 

       <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:id="@+id/second_layout">
         .
         .

         .

       </LinearLayout> 

   </ViewFlipper 
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your java program create a ViewFlipper object.

```
    ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById( R.id.flipper);
```

And call

```
    vf.showNext();
```

You can also apply animation that seems switching layouts from right to left. Thanks...

```
    vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( getApplicationContext(), R.anim.right_in ));
    vf.setOutAnimation( AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( getApplicationContext(), R.anim.left_out ));
    vf.showNext();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `setContentView(R.layout.secondLayout);`

If that didn't work, you could also put all your views under one layout and set the visibility of the buttons to true and the visibility of the progressbar to false after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ViewAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html)

Answer (score 0):

In a LinearLayout or relative layout if you declare two layouts layouts for progess bar and second containing buttons then when progress bar progress is completed just set progress bar layout visibility as GONE and buttons layout visibility as VISIBLE.
At first buttons layout visibility should GONE.